# Simple user entry forspecial characters in LiveCode fields

Tags: user-interface, unicode, livecode

How can user enter special characters in LiveCode fields using the keyboard. For example to input a name such as "John le Carré" with e acute? Before Unicode it was easy to do with Alt-0233 but this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

LiveCode doesn't provide any special character input tools. Rather it uses the input methods provided by the host operating system. It shouldn't be any different to enter e acute in LiveCode than in any other application.

Comment: I checked that MSWord will still accept entry of special characters by use of Alt-codes - provided NumLock is on (also NotePad). But fields in LiveCode still will not accept this input method. I agree with your comment that it should use the the input methods provided by the host operating system. Is this a bug in LiveCode?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in the latest versions (7.x and higher) of LiveCode. It works in 6.x. A bug report has been submitted to the developers.